# Why are some SoundCloud tracks causing their HTML5 widget to fail?

Tags: html, webkit, widget, soundcloud

I am using SoundCloud's own JavaScript API to embed HTML5 widgets on a site but am finding that often their HTML5 widget will not function correctly: neither the waveform nor the artwork displays correctly. Whether the widget functions as expected seems to be on a track-by-track basis.

This is especially noticeable in the WebKit-based browsers (Chrome & Safari) but I also see the issue in Firefox (all browsers used to test are their respective latest versions).

Checking each browser's dev console shows that the SoundCloud code is triggering DOM INDEX_SIZE_ERR exceptions.

The following JSFiddle demonstrates the problem, both using SC's own API as well as a hard-coded embed HTML copied straight from what's given on the SC track page: http://jsfiddle.net/yoknapatawpha/z6axa/

The Thurston Moore track displays correctly, which suggests that this is an issue related to specific tracks. (It is worth noting have also reproduced this problem in a clean page outside JSFiddle, thus removing any possible interference from other elements on the page.)

Does anyone have any ideas or insight as to what is going wrong?

Comment: I should also point out that this problem persists no matter what method I use to embed the HTML5 widget: using a track's embed HTML as stated on it's page, using SC.Widget, or even just testing the resolved track URL in the Widget API Playground.

Comment: Also, against expectations, the widget functions perfectly as expected for all tracks in IE8.

Comment: hey yoknapatawpha, thanks for the thorough bug report. It seems to be an issue with the application thinking the data is ready before it actually is. The erroneous waveform data is then saved in localStorage, which is why you can reproduce the error on this one track. We're looking at the problem now and hopefully there will be a fix deployed today.

Comment: Not to nag you, Nick, but it's been more than a few days and the bug is still extant. Any chance of an update?

Comment: yeah sorry, didn't get in before the Easter long weekend. I'll see what the progress is tomorrow back in the office and let you know. (also, be sure to "@nickf" me, otherwise I don't get notifications of comments. :-) )

Comment: No probs, comrade @nickf - if software were easy it wouldn't be half as much "fun." :)

Comment: I've just pushed out a new version which should fix this issue. Can you let me know if you run into any further problems?

Comment: @nickf - according to my testing, your fix works perfectly well _except_ for when the SC.oEmbed function is called with optional additional OEmbed parameters as the second argument.

Comment: interesting! I'll take another look this week.